# There are some errors with avahi-daemon when I try to upgrade Xubuntu 21.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, avahi

I have Xubuntu 21.04 64-bit. Every time I do "apt upgrade" I have error messages:

```
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.8-5ubuntu3.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: syntax error: unknown option "--skip-systemd-native"
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 installed avahi-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi-utils:
 avahi-utils depends on avahi-daemon (= 0.8-5ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
 avahi-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Could you help me? Thanks.

I've tried this command to get more info:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo dpkg --configure -a
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://prerelease.keybase.io/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:4 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                                   
Hit:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:8 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                               
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                   
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/shutter/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease                                                                                                          
Ign:12 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                                                                                        
Hit:13 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco Release                                                             
Hit:14 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                              
Hit:11 https://apt.llvm.org/groovy llvm-toolchain-groovy-13 InRelease
Fetched 110 kB in 2s (58,5 kB/s)              
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.8-5ubuntu3.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: syntax error: unknown option "--skip-systemd-native"
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 installed avahi-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi-utils:
 avahi-utils depends on avahi-daemon (= 0.8-5ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
 avahi-utils
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Setting up avahi-daemon (0.8-5ubuntu3.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: syntax error: unknown option "--skip-systemd-native"
dpkg: error processing package avahi-daemon (--configure):
 installed avahi-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of avahi-utils:
 avahi-utils depends on avahi-daemon (= 0.8-5ubuntu3.1); however:
  Package avahi-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package avahi-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avahi-daemon
 avahi-utils
```

```
which invoke-rc.d, dpkg -S $(which invoke-rc.d), apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S $(which invoke-rc.d) | awk -F: '{print $1}')
/usr/bin/dpkg
/usr/bin/apt-cache
```

Comment: You have to try ask APT to help you. Run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f; sudo dpkg --configure -a` . Include all error messages into question, or upload full output to pastebin.

Comment: I've uploaded full output as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove obsolete `sysv-rc` package and reinstall the [corresponding package with `invoke-rc.d` inside it](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Finvoke-rc.d) by

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all sysv-rc
sudo apt-get install --reinstall init-system-helpers
```

and then retry running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: I can't reinstall init-system-helpers. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TNfcwx4MfM/

Comment: Then you have to remove problematic package by `sudo apt-get purge sysv-rc` .

Comment: does not work againg - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qdjh85tF6D/

Comment: Then lets force it `sudo dpkg -P --force-all sysv-rc` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall init-system-helpers` .

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved.